# Pass data from html object to another according to its id in my data base

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

So i have two files: index.php and details modal.php. In the index .php file I managed to create a dynamic  object that displays the title, price and image of a product that is stored in my database. That right there is perfect. As you can see in the image each product has a button that says Detalles (Details) which was generated dynamically.That button opens little window on top of the page(called detailsmodal.php). I want to show the data that is in there depending on the product that I chose. I have tried calling the data from the databse but it can only call the data of product one( meaning that if I click on product 2 it still shows the data of product 1) how can I fix that?
Here are some screenshots and my index.php and detailsmodal.php code.

[In this image on the left is what is shown on detailsmodal.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2kDx.png)

[In this image on the left is what is shown on index.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZMQA.png).

index.php

```html
<?php
require_once'core/init.php';
include'includes/head.php';
?>
<!--Navegacion-->
<?php
include('includes/navigation.php');
?>
<!-- Cabecera-->
<?php
include('includes/headerfull.php');
?>
<!--left side bar-->
<?php
include('includes/leftbar.php');


?>
<?php
$sql =  "SELECT * FROM products WHERE featured = 1";
$featured= $db->query($sql);
?>



<!--Detalles-->


 
 <!--main content-->
 <div class="col-md-8">Main
 <div class="row">
  <h2 id="textoTitulo" class="text-center">Productos destacados</h2>
  <?php while($product= mysqli_fetch_assoc($featured)):?>
  
  <div class="col-md-3">
   <h4><?php echo $product['title']?></h4>
   <img src="<?php echo $product['image']?>" id="producto2"   imagenProducto" alt=<?php echo $product['title']?> class="img-thumb" />
   <p class="list-price text-danger">Precio del Mercado <s>₡<?php echo $product['list_price']?></s></p>
   <p class="price">Nuestro precio: ₡<?php echo $product['price']?></p>
   <button type="button" class="btn butn-sm btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#details-1">Detalles</button>
   <?php include('includes/detailsmodal.php');?>
   
  </div>
  <?php endwhile;?>
  
  </div>
 </div>
 <!--Detalles-->
 <?php

?>
<!--right-->
 <?php
 
include('includes/rightbar.php');
?>
 <!--pie-->
 <?php
include('includes/footer.php');
?>
```

detailsmodal.php

```html
<div class="modal fade details-1" id="details-1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="details-1" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
 <div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
   <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" arial-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
   </button>
   <h4 class="modal-title text-center"><?php echo $product['title']?>
    
   </h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="center-block">
       <img src="images/products/planta1.png" alt="Levis Jeans" id="viewProducto" class="details img-responsive">
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
     <h4>Detalles</h4>
     <p><?php echo $product['description']?></p>
     <hr>
     <p>Precio :<?php echo $product['price']?></p>
     <p>Marca: N/A</p>
     <form action="add_cart.php" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
       <div class="col-xs-3">
        <label for="quantity">Cantidad:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="quantity" name="quantity">
        <p>Disponibles: 3</p>
       <div class="form-group">
       <label for="size"></label>
       Size:<select name="size" id="size" class="form-control">
        <option value="36">36</option>
        <option value="40">40</option>
        <option value="50">50</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
       </select>
      </div>

       </div>
       
      </div>

     </form>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
  <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
  <button class="btn btn-warning" type="submit"><img class="cartPNG" src="images/logos/cart.png"> Agregar a Carrito</button>
 </div>
 </div>
 
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because you have give all modal with same id so it will call always first modal with same id.Just look at updated code.

```html
<?php
require_once'core/init.php';
include'includes/head.php';
?>
<!--Navegacion-->
<?php
include('includes/navigation.php');
?>
<!-- Cabecera-->
<?php
include('includes/headerfull.php');
?>
<!--left side bar-->
<?php
include('includes/leftbar.php');


?>
<?php
$sql =  "SELECT * FROM products WHERE featured = 1";
$featured= $db->query($sql);
?>



<!--Detalles-->


 
 <!--main content-->
 <div class="col-md-8">Main
 <div class="row">
  <h2 id="textoTitulo" class="text-center">Productos destacados</h2>
  <?php while($product= mysqli_fetch_assoc($featured)):?>
  
  <div class="col-md-3">
   <h4><?php echo $product['title']?></h4>
   <img src="<?php echo $product['image']?>" id="producto2"   imagenProducto" alt=<?php echo $product['title']?> class="img-thumb" />
   <p class="list-price text-danger">Precio del Mercado <s>₡<?php echo $product['list_price']?></s></p>
   <p class="price">Nuestro precio: ₡<?php echo $product['price']?></p>
   <button type="button" class="btn butn-sm btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#details-<?php echo $product['id'];?>">Detalles</button>
   <?php include('includes/detailsmodal.php');?>
   
  </div>
  <?php endwhile;?>
  
  </div>
 </div>
 <!--Detalles-->
 <?php

?>
<!--right-->
 <?php
 
include('includes/rightbar.php');
?>
 <!--pie-->
 <?php
include('includes/footer.php');
?>



//modal.php file

<div class="modal fade details-1" id="details-<?php echo $product['id'];?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="details-1" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
 <div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
   <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" arial-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
   </button>
   <h4 class="modal-title text-center"><?php echo $product['title']?>
    
   </h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="center-block">
       <img src="images/products/planta1.png" alt="Levis Jeans" id="viewProducto" class="details img-responsive">
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
     <h4>Detalles</h4>
     <p><?php echo $product['description']?></p>
     <hr>
     <p>Precio :<?php echo $product['price']?></p>
     <p>Marca: N/A</p>
     <form action="add_cart.php" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
       <div class="col-xs-3">
        <label for="quantity">Cantidad:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="quantity" name="quantity">
        <p>Disponibles: 3</p>
       <div class="form-group">
       <label for="size"></label>
       Size:<select name="size" id="size" class="form-control">
        <option value="36">36</option>
        <option value="40">40</option>
        <option value="50">50</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
       </select>
      </div>

       </div>
       
      </div>

     </form>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
  <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
  <button class="btn btn-warning" type="submit"><img class="cartPNG" src="images/logos/cart.png"> Agregar a Carrito</button>
 </div>
 </div>
 
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So with that if i click on second product i get information of second product?? And if i clck on third product i get info of third product?

Comment: tried itand it worked, thank you, can you explain to me how it worked

Comment: It is very simple you have given same id to all modal so it will open only first modal when you click on any button so I have just given unique id to all your modal in html and button so it will open unique modal